# MapsDirectionsTask Windows phone is not populating the End Label

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, map-directions

I wanted to display End Label in `MapsDirectionsTask` . I am using the below snippet

```
MapsDirectionsTask directionToATM = new MapsDirectionsTask();
LabeledMapLocation endLabelOnMap = new LabeledMapLocation("Test",
new GeoCoordinate(13.0022,077.5980));
directionToATM.End=endLabelOnMap;
directionToATM.Show();
```

But The End Label which is marked as "Test" is not populating in launcher.Also I tried to set the End label explicitly.

```
directionToATM.End.Label="Test";
```

But it is throwing exception of

> "attempted to read write protected memory. this is often an indication
>   that other memory is corrupt"

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused over what the `LabeledMapLocation` uses the specified label for.

The value you give it will not be shown on the label displayed on the map but will be used in place of the location in the locations/search entry box

[image: Search showing name of end location]

and also in the list of directions

[image: Directions including the name of the end location]

It is not shown on the pin on the map.

Yes the name could be considered misleading.

Note. Above images from the 8.0 WVGA 152 emulator.

Comment: When I am changing the Text "Test" it is not reflecting properly in the search entry box... thats my concern.

Comment: @Subhamoy which version are you using?

Comment: Windows Phone 8...The built in maps